# CSS property update not working with mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to implement accordion.
My accordion should expand on mouse hover on the "accordian head".
And also mouse click on "accordian head" should show/hide the accordion-body.

I got the show/hide working through CSS on hover.
But when i club mouse click event , the functionality is not working

here is the sample

http://jsfiddle.net/yf4W8/157/

```
.accordion-body{display:none;}.accordion:hover div{display:block;}
```

Comment: double quotes are missing for `"none"` and `"block"`

Comment: The problem was, show/hide not working on hover after performing a mouse click.

Answer (score 2):

you need to change

```
myDivElement.style.display = none;
myDivElement.style.display = block;
```

to

```
myDivElement.style.display = "none";   //double quotes are missing
myDivElement.style.display = "block";  //double quotes are missing
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yf4W8/159/)

Comment: Thanks ozil.This is one more problem i would like to share.

Comment: I  mean to say, the on hover show/hide is working. once mouse click happens, the hover is not functioning.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a working demo, please check the link below not it is working on mouse click. Replace your JavaScript code with this and remove the css properties.

```
    function expandAccordionBody(){
        var myDivElement = document.getElementById("accbody" );
        var cStyle=window.getComputedStyle(myDivElement, null);
        if(cStyle.display=='block'){
            myDivElement.style.display='none';
        }else{
            myDivElement.style.display='block';
        }
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dr9hna28/1/)

Comment: Hi Randhir, you have removed mouse hover, i need that show/hide on both hover and mouse click

Comment: How can you make that work ? I mean when you going to click on the div it automatically hover the mouse on that. So both hove and click events will fire on same time.
Don't you think both events will conflict ?

Answer (score 0):

I took a liberty to change your code a bit. This code works.
Hope that this is what you meant to do....
Instead of using pure Javascript I used jQuery event click and hover.

here is the link for working code

[click here for DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mackrai2016/27qx1ffu/1/)

HTML code;

```
<div class="accordion">
<div class="headA">
<a href="#">Head</a>
</div>
<div id="accbody" class="accordion-body">
<a href="#">Body</a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS code;

```
.accordion {
  border: 1px solid #444;
  margin-left: 60px;
  width: 30%;
}

.accordion:hover div {
  display: block;
}

.accordion-body a {
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.headA a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

jQuery code;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // on page load hide accordion body
  var accordionBody = $('#accbody');
  accordionBody.hide();
  // first make on click event happening
  // when user clicks on "Head" accordion "Body will show up"
  $('.headA').click(function() {
    if (accordionBody.is(':hidden')) {
      accordionBody.slideDown(400);
    } else {
      accordionBody.slideUp(400);
    }
  });

  $('.headA').hover(function() {
    if (accordionBody.is(':hidden')) {
      accordionBody.slideDown(400);
    } else {
      accordionBody.slideUp(400); // turn this off if you want only to slide down and not back up
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: If still persists you can copy paste my code showed above. Let me know how it turned out for you!!

Comment: But on hovering the "accordion body", the "accordion body" is hiding.

Comment: "accordion body" should be accessible just like menu item on hover

Comment: great @user2555212

Comment: just comment out last line where else is used and slideUp() is called. my note there is " // turn this off if you want only to slide down and not back up"

Comment: if you hover over yellow div accordion menu will show, if you click on yellow it will show and hide(if clicked again). Hover will work when you reload the page. If you comment out last line, when hovering it will not bring it back up again. Otherwise it will slide up on hovering away from yellow div.

Comment: Can i get the hover working without reloading the page?

Comment: If we see a simple menu, they work on mouse click and as well as hover.

Comment: Just trying to implement the same with "accordion" style